# limit search results in fuse.js vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fuse.js

I've implemented fuse.js with this guide : 
https://fusejs.io/
and the code :

```
const Fuse = require("fuse.js");
  var fuse = new Fuse(this.$store.state.vendorProducts, options); 
  var result = fuse.search(this.itemTitle);
```

the result variable includes all the results of search operation.

I want just first 20 results from result. I can slice the result array, but its too slow, because its loaded all data.

How can i limit the search results by for example first 20 items?

Comment: simplest thing you can do in case api doesn't support limiting results is `result.slice(0,20)`

Comment: @CodeManiac thanks for your answer, if i use slice, it will slice after that all data has loaded. I want to just search 20 first items.

Answer (score 6):

Fuse search has search `SearchOpts` that has only param `limit` so

```
const Fuse = require("fuse.js");
  var fuse = new Fuse(this.$store.state.vendorProducts, options); 
  var result = fuse.search(this.itemTitle, {limit: 20});
```

Found this feature from looking into source code.

Comment: At least in Fuse.js 4.00, the `limit` option is just implemented as `slice` of the final result list. So it's not any faster.